# How to use the Factory Pattern with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, factory-pattern

I am stuck in a scenario where I can have many game screens, and I would like to be able to select a game screen using a radio button or with a combo box. 
But the problem is the best way to implement it?

Should I pass in the string of the checkbox or combobox selection to the Factory, or should I use an Enum?  If the Enum is the way to go how do I use it? A simple example would be nice thanks.

Comment: Do you mean a skinnable UI? Like this one? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19782/Creating-a-Skinned-User-Interface-in-WPF

Comment: I think that actually modifies an existing  user control. 
What I would like is to be able to add a new user control to `Grid.Children[reservedIndex]`  at run time

Comment: Why do you need to create a new user control? It is somewhat unclear what you mean by 'theme'.

Comment: @KendallFrey edited it to be screens. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like using Enums instead of magical strings in this scenario, because it prevents problems caused by typos, and makes the options available to intellisense.

```
namespace TheGame 
{
    // declare enum with all available themes
    public enum EnumGameTheme { theme1, theme2 };

    // factory class
    public class ThemeFactory 
    {
        // factory method.  should create a theme object with the type of the enum value themeToCreate
        public static GameTheme GetTheme(EnumGameTheme themeToCreate) 
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
            // TODO return theme
        }
    }

    // TODO game theme class
    public class GameTheme { }
}
```

Code invoking the factory given a theme selected in (say) *lstThemes*:

```
// get the enum type from a string (selected item in the combo box)
TheGame.EnumGameTheme selectedTheme = Enum.Parse(typeof(TheGame.EnumGameTheme), (string)lstThemes.SelectedValue);
// invoke the factory method
TheGame.GameTheme newTheme = TheGame.ThemeFactory.GetTheme(selectedTheme);
```

Code to get available themes as strings:

```
// get a string array of all the game themes in the Enum (use this to populate the drop-down list)
string[] themeNames = Enum.GetNames(typeof(TheGame.EnumGameTheme));
```

Comment: I don't understand how that works, but it looks like a start thanks.

Comment: @LewsTherin I added some comments, hope that helps.